# Modify the Windows failed logon message

Tags: windows, login, security

Is there a way to modify the message that the user sees following the entry of an insecure password, whilst changing/resetting their password, on Windows 7 / 2008 Server machines?

Basically, the error message that is returned to the user is too vague and doesn't explicitly tell them the password rules of the network - I was hoping to modify the message (not catch and verify the password!!) such that the user is better informed.

I have found evidence online that this was possible in Windows XP, due to the use of GINA, but I can't find of how to change this in Windows 7 upwards.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, this must be done using the GINA dll. All windows operating systems (except VISTA) use this libary for login purposes. You can find more information on this page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa375457(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: This answer would be somewhat more useful if you gave an example of how to use the potential solution rather than simply linking to the documentation externally.